# Add responsive custom footer in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, custom, rwd, footer

I created a custom footer but I want it to be responsive.
My code is:

```
<div style="width: 16%; float: left;">
<h3>LOCATION</h3>
<a href="" target="_blank">Map</a></div>
<div style="width: 16%; float: left;">
<h3>SUPPORT</h3>
<a href="">Technical Support</a></div>
<div style="width: 17%; float: left;">
<h3>CONTACT</h3>
<a href="">Contact</a></div>
<div style="width: 17%; float: left;">
<h3>MY ACCOUNT</h3>
<a href="">Sign In</a></div>
<div style="width: 17%; float: left;">
<h3>FOLLOW US AT</h3>
<a href=""><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/117705_facebook_512x512.png"}}" width="33px" height="32px" /></a> 
<a href=""><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/twitter.png"}}" width="31px" height="30px" /></a></div>
```

Normal preview:

[image: Normal preview]

Mobile preview:

[image: Mobile preview]

Comment: are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: I am using Magneto 2.1 and now I want to create responsive footer

Comment: could you please share URL Or code of footer ?

Comment: please see attached screenshot.

Comment: please let me know if works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should avoid inline style if you want it to be responsive.

Secondly add a class to div and use media query.

**For Example:**

```
<div class="footer-links">
    <h3>Location</h3>
</div>
<div class="footer-links">
    <h3>Support</h3>
</div>
<div class="footer-links">
    <h3>Contact</h3>
</div>
<div class="footer-links">
   <h3>My account</h3>
</div>
<div class="footer-links">
    <h3>Follow us</h3>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.footer-links{
    width: 16.66%;
    float: left;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.footer-links {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
}
</style>
```

**Note** If require you can use display:block